# Hive Remote Metastore With Kerberos

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm new to hive and trying to set it up in a relatively secure manner for a test environment.  I want to use a remote metastore so MR jobs can access the DB.  I seem to have things almost working, but when a user with a credential tries to create a database I get:

```
hive> show databases;
OK
default
hive> create database testdb;
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException User: hdfs/hadoopserver.sub.dom.com@SUB.DOM.COM is not allowed to impersonate myuserid@SUB.DOM.COM)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

I can run 'show databases' ok.  I have "hive --service metastore" running as hdfs with hdfs/hadoopserver.sub.dom.com@SUB.DOM.COM as the principal.  I'm running hive as "myuserid" on the same box.  I don't know if it's related, but if I try to run hive from another system I get a GSS Initiate error unless I use the same principal (hdfs/hadoopserver.sub.dom.com@SUB.DOM.COM) for hive.metastore.kerberos.principal.  Is that expected?

When I try googling this I see similar issues, but they message about not being able to impersonate only shows the single part user name where for me it's showing the realm.  I tried playing with the auth_to_local property, but it didn't help.  Map Reduce and HDFS operations are working fine.

In core-site.xml I have:

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

In hive-site.xml I have:

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore</value>
  <description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>password</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://hadoopserver.sub.dom.com:9083</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file</name>
  <value>/etc/hadoop/hdfs.keytab</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>hdfs/hadoopserver.sub.dom.com@SUB.DOM.COM</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.execute.setugi</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run hive metastore as user "hive" (hive/domain@Realm) and then configure hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts and hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups to '*'.
This works.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

once you added the proxy configs in core-site.xml, e.g  hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups, where hdfs is user who started hiveserver, then add hive.server2.enable.doAs=false to impersonate other user/groups.

Comment: If you set the doas to false, all the security will go off since all the queries will be executed as user hive.